# How to get LibreOffice Writer to use "English (UK)" spell check?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support, spell-checking

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, I installed all that was necessary according to the `gnome-control-center` for the `English (UK)` language pack, but yet still if I go into the LibreOffice Writer (it works partially in some of the other LibreOffice applications) and select `English (UK)` from the list of possible spell checks it will instantly change it back to `English (USA)` when I click anywhere or try to check the spelling of something.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the `English (UK)` spell checker to work in LibreOffice Writer?

Comment: Try installing the `hunspell-en-gb` package and restart LibreOffice afterwards.

Comment: @ByteCommander: That package is already installed.

Comment: I know you made the changes in Ubuntu, but did you set it in Libre office?  Tools, options, language settings, languages.

Comment: @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram: Oh! It worked! You shouldn't really need to do that though, setting it in the quick way at the bottom should really do the trick. But anyway, please do post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you made the changes in Ubuntu, but did you set it in Libre office? Tools, options, language settings, languages.

I know it should seem that you should not have to do this, and maybe it is a bug in Libre Office, but I have found a lot of the time that for some reason a lot of open source software has their own setting for things like this.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `hunspell-en-gb` package.

Answer (score 1):

Start the application by typing `<Alt>+<F2>` and running the command

```
env LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8 libreoffice --writer
```

Obviously there should be better ways, but this one works.